# reportNewIncomingCall completion not called

Tags: swift, voip, callkit

The [reportNewIncomingCall](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider/1930694-reportnewincomingcall) completion argument isn't being called, which means that I'm not getting any feedback as to why my VOIP app isn't displaying the call receiving alert.

```
    func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) {
    // 1.
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
    update.hasVideo = hasVideo

    // 2.
    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
        if error == nil {
            // 3.
            let call = Call(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
            self.callManager.add(call: call)
        }

        // 4.
        completion?(error as? NSError)
    }
}
```

I am taking this from a [Ray Wanderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/701-callkit-tutorial-for-ios).

I copied the code as exactly as possible.  It works in the tutorial but not in my project.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

This is what I didn't do....This solved it.

Comment: bro, you save my day.

Comment: @Ravi Glad to hear it!

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This is how you add the capability https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-capabilities-to-your-app#Add-a-capability